# separate footer to three columns

Tags: html, css, footer

I am trying to make my footer divided into three columns in one row. The left will be my Copyright; Middle will be social media; right will be my contact.

I've been trying and reading and watching so many stuff and I'm finding it really difficult to get done. Could someone help me out please - I'll post my codes below.

It would be very much appreciated if you could also explain what you have done so I can learn for future references. Please use simple terms... as you can see I am very much a beginner haha.

Thank you.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Slideshow */
.section1{
    background: url(files/home-slideshow-001.jpeg);
    height: 90vh;
    background-size: cover;
}
#overlay{
    font-family: Oswald;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 3vw;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
/* End Slideshow */

/* Footer */
footer{
    background: #111111;
    height: 10vh;
}
.copyright, p{
    color: whitesmoke;
}

.contact{
    color: whitesmoke;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: whitesmoke;
}
/* End Footer */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Home - Motive Media Productions</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="section1">
            <div id="overlay">
                <h1>Text</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <footer>
        <div class="copyright">
            <p>&copy; 2018</p>
        </div>
        <div class="brands">
            <div class="social-media">
                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
                        <img src="files/facebook.png"></a>
                    <a href="http://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank">
                        <img src="files/instagram.png"></a>
                    <a href="http://www.twitter.com/" target="_blank">
                        <img src="files/twitter.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contact">
            <li class="contact-list">
                <a href="00">00</a>
            </li>
            <br>
            <li class="contact-list">
                <a href="mailto:hi@hi.com">hi@hi.com</a>
            </li>
        </div>
    </footer>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution and suggestion I can give you is to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). By simply adding `display:flex` to footer you will have your 3 columns, then you can adjust different properties to control size, alignment, etc:

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Slideshow */
.section1{
    background: url(files/home-slideshow-001.jpeg);
    height: 90vh;
    background-size: cover;
}
#overlay{
    font-family: Oswald;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 3vw;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
/* End Slideshow */

/* Footer */
footer{
    background: #111111;
    min-height: 10vh;
    display:flex;
}
footer > div {
  flex:1;
}
.copyright, p{
    color: whitesmoke;
}

.contact{
    color: whitesmoke;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: whitesmoke;
}
/* End Footer */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Home - Motive Media Productions</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="section1">
            <div id="overlay">
                <h1>Text</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <footer>
        <div class="copyright">
            <p>&copy; 2018</p>
        </div>
        <div class="brands">
            <div class="social-media">
                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
                        <img src="files/facebook.png"></a>
                    <a href="http://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank">
                        <img src="files/instagram.png"></a>
                    <a href="http://www.twitter.com/" target="_blank">
                        <img src="files/twitter.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contact">
            <li class="contact-list">
                <a href="00">00</a>
            </li>
            <li class="contact-list">
                <a href="mailto:hi@hi.com">hi@hi.com</a>
            </li>
        </div>
    </footer>
</html>
```

Comment: I have added the Flexbox onto the footer. Although they are all aligned to the centre the contact information on the right (Class="Brands") is still shifted a notch away from the right. I have gone on to Chrome to inspect the code and I can see the Contact Div is split into a table - I am assuming because it is on a list. The table has two rows and two columns instead of one. How can I remove the excess column to make everything centred evenly or at least move the text to the other column. This table isn't actually visible on the web page. I can only see it when I over over it on inspect.

Comment: @TheChasers you are using `li` element so may remove it and use span instead